# Determine the right my.cnf file to tune

Tags: mysql5

In a Centos VPS i want to tune Mysql Server:

```
find -name *my*cfn
./usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.77/my-huge.cnf
./usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.77/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
./usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.77/my-small.cnf
./usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.77/my-medium.cnf
./usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.77/my-large.cnf
./usr/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf
./usr/share/mysql/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
./usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf
./usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf
./usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf
./etc/my.cnf
```

The content of /etc/my.cfn is:

```
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

it is too small, isn't it? do i have to put here my values for parameters
key_buffer_size
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 
innodb_log_file_size
etc??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's the configuration file without any settings. No problem with that. You can either create `[mysqld]` section and tune whatever you want in it, or you can copy one of the example files (`./usr/share/mysql/*`) to `/etc/my.cnf` and tune that.

To check if `/etc/my.cnf` is getting used, run `mysqld --help --verbose | head -n 20` and look for lines like:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```